# gwt beginner- where to create WAR folder in project having AWS SDK and GWT SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, gwt2

I am trying to create a web app that uses Amazon SDK (to be deployed using Elastic Beanstalk) and also uses Google Web Toolkit.

I have created an entry point class and added some code also. Now when I try to compile GWT, it asks me for location of WAR folder- is there a specific place where the WAR should go? Is the location to be configured as per Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, or can I put the WAR anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is a war folder inside your project.
Just compile your project using GWT-Compiler and zip the war folder.
Rename it to .war